# Create New Column With List Comprehension Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, list-comprehension

I am trying to create a new column that contains city names. I also have a list containing the city names needed and CSV files that have city names under different column names.

What I am trying to do is to check whether the city names in the list exist in a specific range of columns of the CSV files and fill that particular city name in the new column City.

My code is:

```py
 
 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
 
City_Name_List = ['Amsterdam', 'Antwerp', 'Brussels', 'Ghent', 'Asheville', 'Austin', 'Boston', 'Broward County', 
                  'Cambridge', 'Chicago', 'Clark County Nv', 'Columbus', 'Denver', 'Hawaii', 'Jersey City', 'Los Angeles', 
                  'Nashville', 'New Orleans', 'New York City', 'Oakland', 'Pacific Grove', 'Portland', 'Rhode Island', 'Salem Or', 'San Diego']
 
 
data = {'host_identity_verified':['t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t'],
      'neighbourhood':['Amsterdam, North Holland, Netherlands', 'Amsterdam, North Holland, Netherlands', 'NaN',
                       'Amsterdam, North Holland, Netherlands', 'Amsterdam, North Holland, Netherlands',
                        'Amsterdam, North Holland, Netherlands', 'Amsterdam, North Holland, Netherlands', 'NaN',
                        'Amsterdam, North Holland, Netherlands', 'Amsterdam, North Holland, Netherlands'],
      'neighbourhood_cleansed':['Oostelijk Havengebied - Indische Buurt', 'Centrum-Oost', 'Centrum-West', 'Centrum-West', 'Centrum-West',
                                'Oostelijk Havengebied - Indische Buurt', 'Centrum-Oost', 'Centrum-West', 'Centrum-West', 'Centrum-West'],
     'neighbourhood_group_cleansed': ['NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN'],
      'latitude':[ 52.36575, 52.36509, 52.37297, 52.38761, 52.36719, 52.36575, 52.36509, 52.37297, 52.38761, 52.36719]}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 
 
df['City']  = [x for x in City_Name_List if x in df.loc[:,'host_identity_verified':'latitude'].values][0]
```

When I run the code, I get this message:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/YAZAN/PycharmProjects/Yazan_Work/try.py", line 63, in <module>
    df['City'] = [x for x in City_Name_List if x in df.loc[:,'host_identity_verified':'latitude'].values][0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This due to the face that the City Amsterdam in the data is followed by other words.

I want my output to be as follow:

```py
0    Amsterdam
1    Amsterdam
2    Amsterdam
3    Amsterdam
4    Amsterdam
5    Amsterdam
6    Amsterdam
7    Amsterdam
8    Amsterdam
9    Amsterdam
Name: City, dtype: object
```

I tried relentlessly to solve this issue. I tried to use `endswith`, `startswith`, regex, but to no avail. I might be using both methods wrongly. I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Basic Solution Using [`Pandas.DataFrame.Apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```py
df['City'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: [x if x in row.loc['neighbourhood'] for x in City_Name_List][0],
    axis=1
)
```

Following execution of the above, `df['city']` will contain a city (defined by its inclusion in `City_Name_List`) if one is found within the `'neighbourhood'` column of each row.

#### Modified Solution

You could be a bit more explicit my specifying that `City` should populate on the first substring present before the first occurrence of `,` within the `'neighbourhood'` field of each row. This may be a good idea if the `'neighbourhood'` column is reliably uniform in structure as it could help to mitigate against any unwanted behaviour arising from similarly named cities, cities that are substrings of other cities in `City_Name_List` etc.

```py
df['City'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: [x if x in row.loc['neighbourhood'].split(',')[0] for x in City_Name_List][0],
    axis=1
)
```

**Note:** The above solutions are simply examples of how you may resolve the problems that you are having. They do not take into account proper handling of exceptions, edge cases etc. As ever you should take care to account for such considerations in your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When Applying your code, I also got NaN in the new column. But I changed np.nan to x and it filled it with the desired city name. Much appreciated. One small question, not all my data files have the city name in a column called neighbourhood I know is that the city name is located between the columns host_identity_verified and latitude. How can I change the code to capture that?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when you say `x in df.loc[]` you are not checking if the city name is in each particular string, but rather if the city name is in the entire Series, which it is not. What you need is something like this:

```
df['city'] = [x if x in City_Name_list else '' for x[0] in df['neighbourhood'].str.split(',')]
```

This will split each row in df['neighborhood'] along the commas and return the first value, then check if that value is in your list of city names and if so then place it in the 'city' Series.

Comment: I am getting this error when running the code:     "Length of values "
ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (10)

Comment: Oh I apologize, I didn't see all the data and realize that there are NaN values. There needs to be an else clause in that list comprehension.

Comment: That would cause there not to be a value for city for every value in the dataframe, so the differing lengths cause an issue. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I am sorry, but the code still didn't work. I am really thankful for you taking the time in checking my question. Much appreciated.

Comment: I realized I had a misplaced indexer. The [0] should come after x, not the .str.split() method. Calling [0] on that method only returns the first row in the dataframe. Answer has been fixed, but glad to see you found a solution that works.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['City'] = df['neighbourhood'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x.split(',') if i in City_Name_List])
df['City'] = df['City'].apply(lambda x: "" if len(x) == 0 else x[0])
```

Comment: Apply is slower than vectorized `Series.str` methods in pandas

Comment: Please submit a vectorized answer :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I partially got what I want, but when there are NaN values in the original column, the row turns out empty in the new column. One more thing, since I am working with more than 2000 CSV files, and not all of them have the column named neighbourhood, but what I know is that the city name is located between the columns host_identity_verified and latitude, is it possible to keep df.loc[:,'host_identity_verified':'latitude'] in the code?

Comment: `df['neighbourhood'].str.split(',')[0]` in @LiamFiddler's answer is an example of a vectorized str method in pandas, which you probably already know. It removes at least one apply or list comprehension. I have a feeling his use case is more complicated than can be easily answered.

Comment: I had a misplaced indexer, which was causing it to behave incorrectly, but the overall solution works.